# return method cannot find symbol

Tags: java, methods

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    {
        int  sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + d[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
// says cant find symbol "sum"
```

Comment: Read up on Java variable scopes...

Comment: Note that the `sum` referenced in `return sum` is OUTSIDE of the brackets in which you defined `sum`.

Comment: Nice code snippet!  Do you mind actually including a question?

Answer (score 6):

Yep, you were trying to use the variable you defined in a scope it was not valid in...

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] d)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
  {
     int  sum = 0;      //definition
     for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++)
     {
        sum = sum + d[i][j];
     }
  } //scope of sum variable ends here

  return sum; //not valid access!!! sum is not defined here.
}
```

Put it one round outer:

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] d)
{
  int  sum = 0;      //definition
  for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++)
     {
        sum = sum + d[i][j];
     }
  }    
  return sum; //not valid access!!!
}   //scope of sum ends here
```

**However** you have another issue... You add **double** values to an integer... I'm not sure you want that, even if you need to get an integer back, I'd add them as doubles, and return an integer...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] d) {
for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
{
int  sum = 0;
 for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++)
 {
    sum = sum + d[i][j];
 }
}return sum;
}
```

You defined sun variable in outer  for loop block and access it outside of that block
you should initialize it before for loop starts

Answer (score 0):

Yes as ppeterka66 says u have to change the scope of variable. As block variable are visible to their block. So u need to define sum in main method.

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] d)
{

    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + d[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```